# Log Transformation in statistics course

Tags: statistics, logarithms

This step was made during a proof for me today by my lecturer. Bit of background, $n=0$ is assumed. I don't understand how we get from (1) to (2). I can see why the second part is equal to $0$, and the first part is equal to $1$, but not why this is not apples and cows but have anything to do with each other.

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{m=n}^k(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m))=1,$$
> $\ln$ transform:
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{m=n}^k\ln(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m))=0$$

Tyvm for the help.

Comment: You get the second equation by taking the logarithm of the first equation. Note that the logarithm is a continuous function, so you can push it through limits. Then simply use the properties of the logarithm to turn the logarithm of a product into a sum of logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{m=n}^k(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m))=1,$$

then taking the logarithm of both sides, and using that the logarithm is continuous to move the limits, we get that

$$0=\ln(1)=\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{m=n}^k(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m))\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\ln\left(\prod_{m=n}^k(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m))\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{m=n}^k\ln(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m)).$$

If you're unsure why the sum turns into a product, just recall the rule $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$. The reason to do this transformation is usually because sums are very widely studied and understood, and so we want to be able to use their theory to study products as well.

Comment: ty so much for taking the time to make this answer. it makes perfekt sence now

Comment: If i may ask one question, in the next step of the proof the limit for k is removed without changing anything else. why is this possible?

Comment: @SimonHansen that doesn't sound right. What you could do is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{m=n}^k\ln(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=n}^\infty\ln(1-\mathbb{P}(A_m)),$$so perhaps it's just a typo?